# Show the left shift $T$ and $T^{-1} $ are measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, product-measure

Let $X=\{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. So an element of $X$ is given by a sequence $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$, where $x_i \in \{0,1 \}$.

Let $\mu_i$ be a probability measure on $(\{0,1 \}, \mathcal{P}(\{0,1 \}))$, where $\mu_i(\{0\})= \mu_i (\{1 \})= \frac{1}{2}$.

Define $\mu = \Pi_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} \mu_i$, and $B = \bigotimes_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{P}(\{0,1 \})$.

Let $T: X \rightarrow X$ be the Bernoulli shift defined by $T(x_i)=x_{i-1}$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Show $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are measurable and $T$ is measure-preserving.

---

Attempt:

Let $A \in B$. To show that $T$ is measurable, I want to show that $T^{-1}(A)= \{x_{i+1} :  (x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} \in A \} \in B$.

Define $H= \{A \subset X : T^{-1}(A) \in B \}$. I showed that $H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So $B \subset H$. Thus, $T$ is measurable.

To show that $T^{-1} $ is measurable, can I do the same thing using $\sigma$-algebras? I'm not sure about this part.

To show that $T$ is measure-preserving, I need to show that $\mu(A)= \mu(T^{-1}(A))$ for all $A\in B$. I don't have any clues for this part either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $T^{-1}$? Right-shift operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- I don't see a problem with showing measurability of $T^{-1}$ similarly to $T$, it should work analogously since $T$ appears to be bijective on $X$
- in order to show that $\mu(A)= \mu(T^{-1}(A))$ for all $A\in B$, it suffices to show equality for all *cylinder sets* because they form an $\cap$-stable generator of $B$

Comment: Thank you for the notes. May I ask what does it mean to say cylinder sets from an $\cap$-stable generator of $B$. Why is it enough to show the equality for cylinder sets?

Comment: @csiqrucalree $\cap$-stable generator means that the cylinder sets are closed under intersection (if $A$,  $B$ are cylinder sets then also $A\cap B$ is a cylinder set) and they generate the $\sigma$-algebra. In general, if two finite measures agree on such an $\cap$-stable generator then they must already be equal. see e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Example